# svn:needs-lock=* in auto-props

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Edit: in Windows you need to make the same changes to the Linux config file 
%AppData%\Roaming\Subversion\config

Enable autoprops and added the * = svn:needs-lock=*

and bobs ya uncle

EDIT: I dropped TortoiseSVN and grabbed a copy of the repo on a linux system, it came down locked, I also touched a new file and added it and it had the lock, so TortoiseSVN has an issue with the permissions.

Using svn, version 1.8.8 (r1568071) compiled Aug 13 2014, 17:12:39 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

trying to setup auto needs-lock for committed items to the repo,

in /etc/subversion/config I have set enable-auto-props = yes under [miscellany], I have removed the white space as well, as I read this causes and issue

Under autoprops I have set *.jpg = svn:mime-type=image/jpeg;svn:needs-lock=* as a test also added * = svn:needs-lock=*

I open TortoiseSVN on me windows machine, add and commit and .JPG file to the repo, check the properties and there is no lock function set. If I do it manually with TortoiseSVN it works.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You **must** to read about `svn:needs-lock` property, how it works and for what it's intended

> If present on a file, tells the client to make the file read-only in the working copy, as a reminder that the file should be locked before editing begins

- You have to lock|unlock every file by hand
- Auto-properties used only for new files, added to WC, not for files already in repo

Comment: Yeah I have gotten the SVN:Needs-lock to work on the linux server that the SVN system is based on by checking out the repo and adding files, they get the SVN:needs-lock property. However if I checkout the repo in windows and add a file and upload it, it does not have the property.